# onAttach() never called in DialogFragment

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I try to implement a callback from a `DialogFragment`.
There is a good example, but they don't open this `DialogFragment` from a `Fragment`.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

So here is my code:

```
public class EditDateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    EditDateDialogListener mListener;

    /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
    public interface EditDateDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    }


    public static EditDateDialogFragment newInstance( int currentCategoryId ) {
        EditDateDialogFragment p = new EditDateDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("currentRecordId", currentCategoryId);
        p.setArguments(args);
        return p;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mCurrentRecordId = getArguments().getInt("currentRecordId");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onAttach(SherlockActivity activity) {

        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            // Instantiate the EditDateDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (EditDateDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement EditDateDialogListener");
        }

    }

        @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_edit_date, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Set Date...").setView(v).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("", "Dialog confirmed");

                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EditDateDialogFragment.this);

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Abort", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("", "Dialog abort");
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create();
    }
}
```

In RecordDetailFragment.java i implement the interface and create a new instance of the EditDateDialogFragment at this way (just the important parts):

```
public class RecordDetailFragment extends SherlockFragment implements EditDateDialogFragment.EditDateDialogListener {
...
 DialogFragment editDateFragment = EditDateDialogFragment.newInstance( recordId );
             editDateFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditDateDialogFrame");
@Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        LOGD(TAG, "Overriden Dialog confirmed");
        //((EditDateDialogFragment) dialog).mDatePicker;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
...
}
```

Now the public void `onAttach(SherlockActivity activity)` in the `EditDateDialogFragment` is never called, because I create the `DialogFragment` from a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`?
How to fix this?

UPDATE:
In the RecordDetailFragment I insert this into the onCreate()

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    EditDateDialogFragment dpf = (EditDateDialogFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("EditDateDialogFragment");
    if (dpf != null) {
        dpf.setListener((EditDateDialogListener) this);
    }
}
```

I changed the instantiation of the DialogFragment to

```
 EditDateDialogFragment editDateFragment = EditDateDialogFragment.newInstance( recordId );
             editDateFragment.setListener((EditDateDialogListener) this);
             editDateFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditDateDialogFragment");
```

Note the EditDateDialogFragment instead of DialogFragment.
I'm not sure how to update the reference in the dialog.

Answer (score 10):

Just jumped into the same problem, the solution was very simple. Instead of overriding

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {}
```

override this:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {}
```

Everything is now fine with `DialogFragment`.

Answer (score 9):

> How to fix this?

I'm guessing that you want the `RecordDetailFragment` instance to behave as the `EditDateDialogListener` for the `DialogFragment`. If yes then you need to explicitly set it(and update it) as the listener:

```
DialogFragment editDateFragment = EditDateDialogFragment.newInstance( recordId );
editDataFragment.setListener(RecordDetailFragment.this);
editDateFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditDateDialogFrame");
```

Where `setListener()` is a method in the `EditDialogFragment` like this:

```
public void setListener(EditDateDialogListener listener) {
     mListener = listener;
}
```

As the user rotates the phone, for example, the Activity along with its fragments will be recreated and you need to re set the listener to point to the newly created `RecordDetailFragment` instance(you may want to use a `WeakReference` for `mListener`). Something similar you can find [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042495/dialogfragment-retaining-listener-after-screen-rotation/14044934#14044934)(you'll look for the two fragments in the `onCreate`).

**Edit**: In the `onCreate` method of the `Activity`:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    RecordDetailFragment df = (RecordDetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("rdf"); // "rdf" is the tag used when you add the RecordDetailFragment to the activity
    EditDateDialogFragment s = (EditDateDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag"); // "tag" is the string set as the tag for the dialog when you show it
    if (s != null) {
                   // the dialog exists so update its listener
        s.setListener(df);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the Listener update working. The desciption where I have to update the listener reference in your comment are a bit unprecise to me.

Comment: @No3x Can you share some information/code on how you did the listener update?

Comment: I'm confused.. In which activity? I want to communicate between the Fragment and the DialogFragment.

Comment: @No3x And where do you use those two fragments? Aren't they placed in a `FragmentActivity` / `Activity`?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in the onCreateDialog cast the mListener to the getActivity():

```
try {
    mListener = (EditDateDialogListener) getActivity();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
            + " must implement EditDateDialogListener");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "modern" approach is to use the new [Fragment Result API](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#kotlin).

Add a result listener on Fragment A (parent) onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    childFragmentManager.setFragmentResultListener("requestKey", this) { key, bundle ->
        val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
    }

}
```

Wherever you need, set result on child Fragment B (on a button click listener, for instance):

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val result = "resultSample"

    setFragmentResult("requestKey", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
}
```

More info on the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#kotlin